# Getting text in strong with Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm trying to get the text inside `<strong>`.
Html code is:

```
<div>
    <a class="business-link"></a>

    <a class="business-link">
        <strong>Text</strong>
    </a>

    <a class="business-link"></a>
</div>
```

There are multiple `business-link` class on the page, I need only the one who contain a `strong`.
There are multi `strong` on the page, but only one inside a `business-link` class.

I tried:

```
browser.a(:class => /business-link/).strong.text
```

and

```
browser.link(:class => /business-link/).strong.text
```

But when trying:

```
unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>"strong"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `browser.a(:class => /business-link/).strong.text` is that it finds the first link with class "business-link" *and then,* within that link, looks for the `strong` element. The first link is not the one with the `strong` element. What you really want to tell Watir is to find the first link that also contains a `strong` element.

You could create a collection of the links and iterate through them until you find a `strong` element:

```
business_links = browser.links(class: 'business-link')
business_link = business_links.find { |link| link.strong.exist? }
business_link.strong.text # or simply `business_link.text`
#=> "Text"
```

If you are comfortable with `:css` (or `:xpath`) locators, this can be more succinctly written as:

```
browser.strong(css: 'a.business-link > strong').text
#=> "Text"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p b.element(:tag_name => 'strong').text
```

The code below print the first strong tag value

```
p b.elements(:tag_name => 'strong')[0].text
```

this will print second one.

```
p b.elements(:tag_name => 'strong')[1].text
```

To iterate all the elements

```
b.elements(:tag_name,'strong').each do |i|
    puts i.text
end
```

Comment: There are multi `strong` on the page, but only one inside a `business-link` class. So it doesn't work